# VBA - Identifying null string

Tags: excel, vba, null

One of my cells appears to be blank but has a length of 2 characters.  I copied the string to [this](http://onlinecalculators.brainmeasures.com/Conversions/StringtoAsciiCalculator.aspx) website and it has identified it as a null string.

I have tried using `IsNull` and `IsEmpty`, as well as testing to see if it is equivalent to the `vbNullString` but it is still coming up as `False`.

How do I identify this string as being `Null`?

Comment: Like the actual "Nul"? Try Char 0.

Comment: Did you try using the `Asc` function to identify the characters' code number?

Comment: That website shows you the hexadecimal character codes, what are they for your data?

Comment: the asc function is saying it is 160

Comment: VBA doesn't use ASCII (as evidenced by `Asc` returning 160, which is greater than 127). It uses UTF-16. Use `AscW` because `Asc` doesn't do what you think it does. You are lucky this time that it returns the same value as `AscW`. (And, use `ChrW`/`ChrW$` instead of `Chr`/`Chr$`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string value that "appears to be blank but has a length of 2 characters" is said to be *whitespace*, not *blank*, not *null*, not *empty*.

Use the `Trim` function (or its `Trim$` stringly-typed little brother) to strip leading/trailing whitespace characters, then test the result against `vbNullString` (or `""`):

```
If Trim$(value) = vbNullString Then
```

The `Trim` function won't strip non-breaking spaces though. You can write a function that does:

```
Public Function TrimStripNBSP(ByVal value As String) As String
    TrimStripNBSP = Trim$(Replace(value, Chr$(160), Chr$(32)))
End Function
```

This replaces non-breaking spaces with ASCII 32 (a "normal" space character), then trims it and returns the result.

Now you can use it to test against `vbNullString` (or `""`):

```
If TrimStripNBSP(value) = vbNullString Then
```

The `IsEmpty` function can only be used with a `Variant` (only returns a meaningful result given a `Variant` anyway), to determine whether that variant contains a value.

The `IsNull` function has extremely limited use in Excel-hosted VBA, and shouldn't be needed since nothing is ever going to be `Null` in an Excel worksheet - especially not a string with a length of 2.

Comment: Could you explain the use of the $ sign in Trim$ and Chr$?

Comment: @VBasic2008 `Trim` takes and returns a `Variant`. `Trim$` takes and returns a `String`. They're aliases. Internally in VBA7.DLL, `Trim` invokes `B_VAR_TRIM`, while `Trim$` invokes `B_STR_TRIM`.

Answer (score 1):

## Chr(160) Issue

160 is the code number of a **Non-Breaking Space**.

Let us say the cell is A1.

In any cell write `=CODE(A1)` and in another (e.g. next to) write `=CODE(MID(A1,2,1))`.

The results are the code numbers (integers e.g. a and b) of the characters.

Now in VBA you can use:

```
If Cells(1, 1) = Chr(a) & Chr(b) Then

End If
```

or e.g.

```
If Left(Cells(1, 1), 1) = Chr(160) then

End If
```