# Check cell value for white space or blank only

Tags: excel, vba

I'm verifying my cell value. The cell value has 5 blank or white spaces. I'm trying to check if the cell is blank or only contains white spaces and NO text or other characters. It's not working though, is the cell value really blank or white space?:

```
if Trim(range("A1").Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString then
    'stop here and do something
end if
```

Comment: `If Application.Trim(Range("A1"))="" Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner i'm now not even sure if it's white space or blank anymore, If i manually put spaces, it work but if i copy the real value of the so call blank, it's not working.

Comment: `If Application.Trim(Application.Clean(Range("A1")))="" Then`

Comment: none of those two works. this blank is a textbox table i copy from a word document into excel.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54204469/1188513) be it? (ASCII 160 characters are not removed by `Trim`)

Comment: AWESOME! YES!...

Answer (score 0):

There is a LOT of blankspace characters (most invisible to "naked eyes"), like when you make a SHIFT+ENTER to breakline into the cell (like < BR/ > in HTML

What I suggest you to do, is to pass to a function to check ALL characters of the cell or textbox.

You can call the function from excel formula like: =Verify(A1), or with another SUB.

Every time your appointments = 0 it is you have only Real Spaces and Nulls and not letters, numbers, special chars, tabs or line breakers.

```
Public Function Verify(FullWord)

    Appointments = 0

    For X = 1 To Len(FullWord)
        Letter = Mid(FullWord, X, 1)

        Select Case Letter

           'Real NULL
           Case Is = ""
           Case Is = vbNullChar  'Chr(0)  Character having a value of 0.
           Case Is = vbNullString    'String having value 0   Not the same as a zero-length string (""); used for calling external procedures. Cannot be passed to any DLL's

           'Real SPACE
           Case Is = " "

           'Other things
           Case Is = vbCr    'Chr(13) Carriage return character
             Appointments = Appointments + 1
           Case Is = vbLf    'Chr(10) Linefeed character
             Appointments = Appointments + 1
           Case Is = vbCrLf  'Chr(13) + Chr(10)   Carriage return - linefeed combination
             Appointments = Appointments + 1
           Case Is = vbNewLine   'Chr(13) + Chr(10)   New line character
             Appointments = Appointments + 1
           Case Is = vbTab   'Chr(9)  Tab character
             Appointments = Appointments + 1
           Case Is = vbBack  'Chr(8)  Backspace character
             Appointments = Appointments + 1
           Case Is = vbFormFeed  'Chr(12) Word VBA Manual - manual page break ?
             Appointments = Appointments + 1
           Case Is = vbVerticalTab   'Chr(11) Word VBA Manual - manual line break (Shift + Enter)
             Appointments = Appointments + 1

           Case Else

           Appointments = Appointments + 1

        End Select
     Next

     Verify = Appointments

End Function
```