# Could not set list property , type mismatch- list box

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, type-mismatch

I am try to add some data from a sheet.

the sheet has the result from SQL server as record set
I am trying to fetch the data to a list box in user form
have a column count as 4 
most of the values are coming. but few cell has value in excel, but not reflecting in List box

for those case i am getting on the below lint as

> "Could not set the list property. Type Mismatch"

```
.List(.ListCount - 1, i - 1) = rw.Cells(1, i).Value
```

---

```
Dim lbtarget As MSForms.ListBox
            Dim rngSource As Range
            Dim rw As Range
            Dim i
            Dim lRow
            Dim strng As String
            Dim lCol As Long, lRow1 As Long

           UserForm1.ListBox1.Visible = True

           lRow = Sheets("macro").Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

             Set rngSource = Sheets("macro").Range("B15:E" & lRow)
             Set lbtarget = UserForm1.ListBox1

              With lbtarget
                .ColumnCount = 4
                .ColumnWidths = "48;120;220"

                For Each rw In rngSource.Rows
                UserForm1.ListBox1.Visible = True
                    If rw.Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
                        .AddItem ""
                        For i = 1 To .ColumnCount
                        Dim texdf
                            texdf = rw.Cells(1, i)
                            Debug.Print texdf
                            .List(.ListCount - 1, i - 1) = rw.Cells(1, i).Value

                        Next
                       End If
                Next

            End With
        UserForm1.ListBox1.Visible = True


Else
MsgBox " NO Data Provided, please enter the SEQ_Number", vbOKCancel
End If
```

Comment: Try, please `.AddItem ` instead of `.AddItem ""`...

Comment: What is the value of `rw.Cells(1, i).Value` and the value of `i` when you get the error?

Comment: The error is probably caused by a value of `Nul` imported with the Server data. VBA doesn't have a data type that accommodates the `Nul` character. Therefore you can't search for it. But you can replace all cells of 0 length with `vbNullString`. On the other hand, if the length of the cell contents = 2 and appears blank, read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204067/vba-identifying-null-string

Comment: Thanks for your feedback & suggestions.  

braX - rw.cells(1,i).value = string (long string len is more than 2300) & i=4 FaneDuru, i have tried change that - Still the same error   
Variatus - Let me try to check the page, and see will it help. 
Thanks to all
Still issue is not resolved

Comment: @Variatus - I have tested the code for chr(160) and did the coding changes - still the same error .. Thanks for your deatils.

Comment: Team, I Have tried a  other option, I am tried paste the value with a text box and its working. But its not getting listed in listbox in column 4 ...... I have tried assigning the value for listbox from textbox - not worked - Error  " Could not set the List property ; type mismatch

Comment: *"But its not getting listed in listbox in column 4"* ... As far as I see you didn't provide for a fourth listbox column when assigning widths via `.ColumnWidths = "48;120;220"` :-)

Comment: @T.M. - the rest space ocpied by colm 4 , no need to assgin it.. by default 1,2,3, - have specified as per my need 4 can be used as default